# limiting float point array of arrays with less decimal points

Tags: numpy, matrix, floating-point-precision

**Problem:**

Our problem is while using machine learning algorithm like PLSA the huge float point values are taking a lot of time. Now, how can we reduce the float point precision to just 2 decimal places and do mathematical operations?

**What we have:**

Initialized with the following numpy command np.zeros([2,4,3],np.float)

```
ndarray: [[[ 0.09997559  0.          0.89990234]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]]

 [[ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.30004883  0.30004883  0.30004883]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]]]


**What we needed:**

[[[ 0.1         0.          0.9]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]]

 [[ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.3         0.3         0.3       ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]]]
```

Comment: That's not how floating-point works.

Comment: Hi Oliver...Is there any alternative for this scenario.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use half precision floats to reduce memory usage (sign bit, 5 bits exponent, 10 bits mantissa). See [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html).

```
>>> b=np.zeros([2,4,3],np.float)
>>> b.nbytes
192
>>> c=np.zeros([2,4,3],np.float16)
>>> c.nbytes
48
```